# macOS - Display Dashboard on external display

Tags: macos, display, dashboard

I have a multi-monitor setup with my MacBook Pro. I have configured Dashboard to appear as Overlay in the Mission Control preference.

[image]

However, whenever I summon the Dashboard it always appears on MacBook's built-in screen. Is there a way I can make Dashboard to appear on one of the connected external display(s)?

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.1 on a 2013 15" retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: I believe it is always shown on the main display. Go to display settings and drag the small menu bar on the macbook display to one of the externals and try summoning dashboard again.

Comment: Thanks @KevinGrabher that indeed worked. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard is always shown on the primary screen.
To set which screen should be used as the primary, go to System Preferences -> Displays. 
Now drag the white bar to the screen that you want to be set as primary.

[image: Display settings]